# How to make UAC block certain application without asking

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, uac

I search for quite a really while about Windows UAC, there are lot of stories telling us how to disable UAC or how to let program able to run without UAC to aware. However I am looking for something entirely different.

What I want is letting UAC !TO BLOCK! applications without asking, as well as applications derived, called, threaded from that application. While adding application to task manager can let it pass, what should I do to let it blocked??

Comment: UAC cannot block applications your thinking of App Locker.

Comment: UAC is unable to block applications, like @Ramhound said. I offered an alternative since UAC can't do what you are wanting to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UAC (User Account Control) is unable to block applications like you want.

I like to use Process Blocker (it's free) to block applications and processes from running, it immediately terminates the application or process perpetually. To block it all you have to do is open Task Manager and determine what processes the application (that you want to prevent from running) is using.

For example, if I don't want Bonjour to be running, ever, then I will go into process blocker, and open up task manager in Windows and find any processes used by Bonjour and add those processes to Process Blocker manually. Once I click "Apply" to save my changes, then Bonjour is terminated and can never start.

The better solution, however, is to find the application and remove it. However, if you only want to use it on demand, you can use process blocker to do this, you will just need to open process blocker and unselect the process(es) every time you want to use the application. This can be worth it if you rarely use the application and don't want it running when you are not using it.

Answer (score 1):

To this date, including the latest version of Windows 10, it seems Microsoft has not built a blacklist into UAC. A process can ask for administration access each time it's run and the current operator of the system must continue to deny it each time.

If you do not ever want a particular process to run, regardless of granting it admin privileges, you may consider the answer provided by user7783780. However, the suggestions in that answer do not really address the original question. It doesn't cover the situation detailed in the question where the operator of the system wants to run an application process and any threads it may spawn, but doesn't want to grant them administrator access and doesn't want to be prompted to grant such access.

It's a valid question about operating a personal computer, I'm not sure why the down votes (maybe the unusual use of exclamation marks?). Short of reverse engineering the software and patching it not to ask for such permissions, I doubt there could be a legitimate way even a power-user could achieve this unless Microsoft adds a "blacklist" feature to UAC.